# Normalization of squeezed vacuum for QFT in the black hole background (Hawking radiation)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, squeezed-states

In the context of BH evaporation, one can represent an initial vacuum as the *final* state containing particles, following [Polchcinski (2016, page 9)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04036)

$$|0\rangle_{a}=\mathcal{N} \exp \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d \omega}{2 \pi} e^{-\omega / 2 T_{\mathrm{H}}} b_{\omega}^{\dagger} \tilde{b}_{\omega}^{\dagger}\right) $$

where $\mathcal{N}$ is the normalization constant.

On the other hand, one can read in *Lectures on quantum gravity* edited by Gomberoff, Marolf (Springer) that the condition for normalizability is

> the average total number of excitations must be finite. If it is not, the state $\left|0_{\rm in}\right\rangle$ does not lie in the Fock space built on the the state $\left|0_{\text {out }}\right\rangle$

We know that in the case of BH evaporation the number of excitations is infinite.

My question is: is that state actually normalizable, if yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that state actually normalizable...?

Yes. To see this, start with the state $U|0\rangle$ with
$$
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
 U = 
 \exp\left(
 \int_0^\infty\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\ 
  f(\omega)\left(b_\omega\tilde b_\omega 
   - b_\omega^\dagger\tilde b_\omega^\dagger\right)
 \right)
\tag{1}
$$
for some real-valued function $f(\omega)$. The operator $U$ is manifestly unitary, so the norm of $U|0\ra$ is the same as the norm of $|0\ra$. Use equation (3.7.50) in ref 1 to get the identity
$$
 U|0\ra = A|0\ra
\tag{2}
$$
with
$$
 A =
 \mathcal{N}
 \exp\left(
 -\int_0^\infty\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\ 
 \tanh\big(f(\omega)\big) b_\omega^\dagger\tilde b_\omega^\dagger
 \right)
\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
 \mathcal{N}
 =
 \exp\left(
 -\int_0^\infty\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\ 
  \log\Big(\cosh\big(f(\omega)\big)\Big)
 \right).
\tag{4}
$$
The function $f(\omega)$ can be chosen so that the state $A|0\ra$ is the state shown in the question, namely
$$
 -\tanh\big(f(\omega)\big) = e^{-\omega/2T}.
\tag{5}
$$
The only thing left to check is that (4) is finite. To see that it is, use the fact that for large $\omega$, equation (5) implies
$$
 -f(\omega)\approx e^{-\omega/2T}\ll 1,
\tag{6}
$$
which in turn implies
$$
 \log\Big(\cosh\big(f(\omega)\big)\Big)
 \sim
 e^{-\omega/T},
\tag{7}
$$
so the integral (4) converges. If we're concerned that the manipulations leading to the identity (2) might not be well-defined, then we can use a regulator, like taking $\omega$ to be a discrete parameter and deferring the continuum limit until the end of the calculation, after all desired inner products have been calculated.

---

Reference:

1. Chapter 3 (Operators and States) in Barnett and Radmore (2002), *Methods in Theoretical Quantum Optics* (Oxford University Press)

Comment: The link defaults to the main page.

Comment: @flippiefanus  Thank you for letting me know!  I removed the broken link.