# Can squeezed vacuum reduce the mass of a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, black-holes, vacuum

Could the negative energy density parts of squeezed light really reduce the mass of a black hole, as stated here (“A pulse of negative energy injected into a charged black hole might momentarily destroy the horizon, exposing the singularity within” LH. Ford)
[Negative Energy, Wormholes and warp drive] http://u2.lege.net/cetinbal/pdfdosya/wormholesjan.pdf

Comment: related for vocabulary    https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/625239/

Comment: What are the "negative energy density parts of squeezed light"? The Wigner function of a squeezed vacuum state is positive everywhere.

Comment: See http://u2.lege.net/cetinbal/pdfdosya/wormholesjan.pdf